# Sum and distinct in acces SQL

Tags: sql, ms-access

I already made a query that this was it result :

```
7  |  3
8  |  4
8  |  2
8  |  1
10 |  3
12 |  4
12 |  1
13 |  3
```

I need new query that take this result and return this :

```
7  |  3
8  |  **7**
10 |  3
12 |  **5**
13 |  3
```

In the left column I need that evry number will appears only once,
and in the right column sum the numbers according to the value in the left column as I showed before.

how to do it?

Comment: Your logic isnt clear. Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

Comment: I tried adding distinct but it's not sum the right column
and sum also didn't work

Comment: @Sportalcraft - you should include your attempted query in your question.

Comment: it us quite complex, and realy hard to explain...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT leftField, SUM(rigthField) as rigthField
FROM YourResult
GROUP BY leftField
```

Comment: I'm getting this error message :
The query does not include the expression 'leftfield' as accumulate function

Comment: You didnt provide the name of the fields. I just use `leftField` as an alias. You need to use the name of your column.

Comment: actually, the correcr translate of the error I got is : 

The query does not include the specified expression 'leftfield' as part of an aggregate function.

Sorry for my mistake!

Comment: Never mind! It worked, just need to add DISTINCT
Thanks!